# end of line in linux and mac

Tags: sed, newlines

I am analyzing a text file looking for a path that is written after a line that starts with "output". The line is something like

```
output xyz/mypath/
```

and I want to extract `xyz/mypath` **without** the final slash.

On my Mac OS X (BSD) and Linux I get different behaviors when I get the path with this 
`basepath=cat $basefile | grep -e ^output\ | cut -d" " -f2 | rev | sed 's@/$@@' | rev`

The tricky part seems to be

`sed 's@/$@@`

which on Mac works, while it does not on Linux. Vice-versa if I do

`sed 's@/@@`
it works on linux not on Mac (BSD).

The trick seems to be related to the end-of-line char $ which is managed differently (maybe at the level of cat. 
Any suggestion to work around this in a way that both Mac and Linux console will do the job?

Comment: I don't get why you are reversing the string - surely that puts the `/` that you want to replace at the _start_ of the line (anchor `^`) rather than at `$`?

Answer (score 1):

That should work as is on Linux as far as I can tell - the `sed` statement at least - but if you want to know what's happening in `sed`'s pattern space you should `l`ook at it:

```
sed 'l;s|/$||;l'
```

I think you could do the whole thing in `sed` like:

```
basepath=$(sed '/^output /!d;s|||;s|/$||' <"$basefile")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have easy access to an OSX machine but your approach is needlessly complex anyway. Just do something like these (depending on your actual input) instead:

```
basepath=$(grep ^output "$basefile" | awk '{print $NF}' | sed 's/[/]$//'
```

or

```
basepath=$(awk '/^output/{print $2}' "$basefile" | sed 's/[/]$//')
```

or even

```
basepath=$(grep -oP '^output\s+\K.+(?=/)' "$basefile")
```

or

```
basepath=$(perl -lne 'print $1 if /^output\s+(.+)\//' "$basefile";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest

```
sed -n '/^output / {s///; s,\(.*\)/,\1,p}'
```

which should work on GNU and OSX sed.

The empty regex in `s///` re-uses the previous regex (`/^output /`)